# Avoid bulkification in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, bulkification, visual-flows

I update/create (upsert via sf-dataloader) each day the data of our contracts. These contracts (customobject EZR) contain the lastname, surname, birthdate etc... I create an ID with this data (sample 13122000jondoe). Each contract must be assigned to a contact. The contact object has also a field with the ID of the contact (same logic).

During the upsert the flow check if whether a suitable contact is available,
if **yes** the contract will be linked to the contact,
if **no** a new contact created and the contract will be linked to the contact.

Sometimes two of the same person are created although it should only be one. I think that is the problem of [bulkification](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5).

How can I avoid this problem?
At the moment I use a workaround, I create the ID in my presystem and sort the ID, next I split the file in two parts. The first contains no duplicate IDs and the second part the rest.

Comment: From what you described it seems like the issue is that the other way around (meaning each Contract record is being handled separately, leading to the creation of two records instead of one record linked to 2 separate contracts). As a workaround, you can move the logic of the Contact creation to an Invocable Apex class that would be called from your Flow.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, we cannot access data from other upserted records in the transaction directly in the Flow.

However, an apex invocable action does have the full list of records getting processed. You could write an invocable Apex method to accept the list of contracts that handles all or part of this process. It could be written to only process records that need a contact created and pass back the ID of the appropriate contact for each of those Contracts if you want to isolate just that logic, or you could pass in all of the records and let it decide which Contracts need a contact to be created